# Increase the 1000 limit for aws lambda results count from execute_sql using rds-data or use a different package?

Tags: aws-lambda, sqlalchemy, boto3, pymysql, aws-rds-data-service

I have been using AWS aurora with python lambda function for executing queries for our application.
The lambda functions works great, but returns only top 1000 results not all. I tried increasing the limit to 5000 by using paginators, couldn't find an appropriate solution to that :

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):

   client = boto3.client('rds-data')
   readParam = event['query'] # readParam = 'select * from table;'
   database1 = event['database'] # Database name

   response = client.execute_sql(
      awsSecretStoreArn='arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxxx:secret:abc/read-XXXX',
      database=database1,
      dbClusterOrInstanceArn='arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:xxxxx:cluster:abcd-abc',
      sqlStatements=readParam
   )

   return {
      'statusCode': 200,
      'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST"
       },
      'body': response
  }
```

`

I have tried using SQLAlchemy and pydataapi and deploying the AWS development package to lambda, that doesn't work. The lambda function doesn't read the appropriate python file having the lambda_handler. The code is as follows:

```
import pymysql.cursors
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
  def lambda_handler(event, context):
    readParam = event['query']
    database1 = event['database']

    engine = create_engine(
       'mysql+pydataapi://',
        connect_args={
           'resource_arn': 'arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:xxxx:cluster:abcd-abc',
           'secret_arn': 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxx:secret:abc/read-XXXX',
        'database': 'mimic_dev'
    }
)

result: ResultProxy = engine.execute(readParam)

return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST"
    },
    'body': result.fetchall
}
```

Is there any better alternate solution to what I have been trying?
Any help appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved.
Resources: [AWS lambda deployment Package in Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html)

And the following code:

```
import pymysql.cursors
import json

from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

def lambda_handler(event,context):
   engine = create_engine(
       'mysql+pydataapi://',
        connect_args={
        'resource_arn': 'arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:xxxxx:cluster:xxxx',
        'secret_arn': 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxx:secret:decima/abcd-abc',
        'database': 'mimic_dev'
    }
)
   result: ResultProxy = engine.execute("select * from person limit 10000")
   resultValue = result.fetchall()
   return json.dumps([dict(r) for r in resultValue])
```